# How to change stream interval dynamically when another stream emits

Tags: rxjs

So I have a stream made of an array of strings.

```
const msgs = ['Searching...', 'Gathering the Data...', 'Loading the Dashboard...'];
const msgs$ = Observable.from(msgs);
```

I need to emit one of these messages sequentially every 3 seconds until `dataFetched$` stream emits - which basically means all data arrived to page. I cannot cycle through them. Once the last message is seen but data hasn't arrived, it shouldn't change.

I can go over each string in `msgs` over time with `RxJS zip` function

```
const longInt$: Observable<number> = Observable.interval(3000);
const longMsgsOverTime$ = Observable.zip(msgs$, longInt$, msg => msg);
```

Then when the `dataFetched$` stream emits I need to switch to `shortInt$` which is

```
    const longInt$: Observable<number> = Observable.interval(1500);
```

And continue displaying the loading messages until the last one is visible. Each message should only be seen once.

It's quite mind bending for me - I can tick some of the requirements but not make it fully working. 
After many tries I arrived to conclusion that we need to wrap `msgs` array in a Subject to prevent cycling though all of them again after we switched from `longInt$` to `shortInt$`.

===================EDIT=====================
Following's ggradnig's answer and code I concocted this ugliness (for debugging purposes):

```
    setLoaderMsg(){
    console.log('%c setting loader msg', 'border: 10px dotted red;');
    const msgs$ = Observable.from(['Searching...', 'Gathering the Data...', 'Loading the Dashboard...', 'Something something...', 'yet another msg...', 'stop showing me...']),
        shortInt$ = Observable.interval(250).pipe(
            tap(v => console.log('%c short v', 'background: green;',v))
        ),
        longInt$ = Observable.interval(3000).pipe(
            tap(v => console.log('%c long v', 'background: red;',v)),
            takeUntil(this.dataFetched$)
        ),
        // interval$ = Observable.interval(3000).pipe(takeUntil(this.dataFetched$)).pipe(concat(Observable.interval(250))),
        interval$ = longInt$.pipe(concat(shortInt$));

    Observable.zip(msgs$, interval$, msg => msg)
    // Observable.zip(msgs$, interval$)
        .pipe(tap(v => {
            console.log('%c v', 'background: black; border: 1px solid red; color: white;', v);
            this.loaderMsg = v;
        }))
        .subscribe(
            () => {},                       //next
            () => {},                       //error
            // () => this.loading = false       //complete
            () => {
                console.log('%c complete', 'background: yellow; border: 2px solid red');
                // this.loading = false;
            }
        );
}
```

Below is a screengrab of my chrome console to see what happens. The `shortInt$` stream would log green message, as you can see it never happens, even though the `dataFetched$` stream emitted (orange dashed border). 
Below the "fetch data emit" log we should see green background messages that would signify that the shortInt$ stream is emitting values.

[image]

================================= 2nd EDIT ========================

Below is `dataFetched$` observable:

```
fetchData(){
    console.log('%c fetching now', 'border: 2px dashed purple');

    // this.initLoader();

    this.dataFetched$ = Observable.combineLatest([
        this.heroTableService.getHeroTableData([SubAggs.allNetworks.key], AggFieldsMap.legends.name),
        this.researchService.benchmark(this.getSubAggsForOverviewTbl()),
        this.multiLineChartService.getEngagementOverTime(this.getSubAggsForNetworkEngagementsOverTimeTable())
    ]).pipe(
        share(),
        delay(7000),
        tap(v => {
            console.log('%c fetch data emit', 'border: 2px dashed orange', v);
        })
    );


    const sub = this.dataFetched$.subscribe(([heroTableRes, benchmarkRes, netByEngRes]: [ITable[], IBenchmarkResponse, any]) => {
         // this.loading = false; ==> moved to dashboard

         //xavtodo: split this shit into .do() or .tap under each http request call
         //hero table logic here
         this.heroTableData = heroTableRes;

         //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
         //engagement-by-network-table
         this.engagementByNetworkData = this.researchService.extractDataForEngagementByNetworkTable(benchmarkRes, this.getSubAggsForOverviewTbl());

         //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
         //network eng over time logic here MULTI LINE CHART
         this.engagementMultiLineData = this.multiLineChartService.extractEngagementData(netByEngRes, this.getSubAggsForNetworkEngagementsOverTimeTable());
         this.networks = this.multiLineChartService.getNetworks();
         this.multilineChartEngagements = Util.getNetworksWithAltNames(this.networks);
         this.publishedContentData = this.multiLineChartService.extractPublishedData(netByEngRes);

         //combined multiline chart
         this.multiLineChartData = {
             publishedData: this.publishedContentData,
             engagementData: this.engagementMultiLineData
         };
     });

    this.addSubscription(sub);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a task for `takeUntil` and `concat`.

The first observable is `longInt$`. It completes as soon as `dataFetched$` emits. For this requirement, you can use `takeUntil`. It takes another observable as a parameter and once that observable emits, the source observable will complete.

From the docs:

> Emits the values emitted by the source Observable until a `notifier` Observable emits a value.

So, the first step would be:

```
const longInt$: Observable<number> = Observable.interval(3000)
    .pipe(takeUntil(dataFetched$));
```

Next, you want to `concat` your other observable, `shortInt$`. Concat will let the first observable complete, then let the second observable take over.

From the docs:

> Creates an output Observable which sequentially emits all values from given Observable and then moves on to the next.

This would look something like this:

```
const longMsgsOverTime$ = Observable.zip(msgs$, 
    longInt$.pipe(concat(shortInt$)), msg => msg);
```

**Note:** If you are using RxJS 5 or lower, replace the pipe(..) statements with the corresponding operator. For example, `.pipe(concat(...))` turns into `.concat(...)`

Here is an example on StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mtyfxd

Comment: I followed your suggestions but I never enter the shortInt$ stream. The data arrives, but the messages keep cycling using the longInt$. My code here http://jsfiddle.net/0w8tkzhx/

Comment: It's due to how you used `zip` -> in your answer you zipped observable of 3 values (array of strings) with longInt$ concated with shortInt$ but the observable intervals never emit `complete` therefore, concat function will never be executed.

Comment: hmm.. longInt$ should complete when the `takeUntil` notifier emits.

Comment: I've added a StackBlitz example in my post, you can check it out :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I still can't get it to work in my app, even when following your example to the letter. I only see `longInt$` emissions when I tap into its stream.

Comment: I updated my question with your code and a screengrab of my chrome console.

Comment: @codeepic - your jsfiddle does not have dataFetch$ observable that emits. Therefore, it does not hit the shortInt$

Comment: @dK - my jsfiddle holds only part of the code - it's just to illustrate the logic in the `setLoaderMsg` method. It emits in the application --> see my answer and the screenshot of my chrome console - it's a message that says "fetch data emit" wrapped in orange dashed border.

Comment: I will assess what the hell is going on in my app that's not working, ggradnig solution makes sense and works as intended on stackblitz and I applied it very thoroughly, but my code never switches from `longInterval$` to `shortInterval$` stream. There must be some timing issue, cause I excluded the side effects.

Comment: @codeepic I assume that there is a problem with the dataFetched$ observable. I cannot see where it is initialized, but could you add this at the end of the initialization: `.pipe(share(), refCount())`. This creates a multicast observable, so your message observable receives exactly the same notification as the original consumer of the API.

Comment: Oh, you probably don't need `refCount()`. It's already included in share

Comment: @ggradnig - I used share() when I initialize `dataFetched$` stream and I also log when the longInt$ completes - it never happens even after `dataFetched$` emitted - as if `takeUntil` didn't work - what a bloody mess. If the stream solution doesn't work, I need to revert to setInterval and loop over array and I definitely don't want to do this.

Comment: hm, really tricky, but I'm eager to solve it. could you include everything related to `dataFetched$` in your post?

Comment: Thanks @ggradnig - I added the code for the whole dataFetched$ stream. It's in a child component of the Angular app.

Comment: Could you try putting `share()` as the last operator in `dataFetched$` ?

Comment: Done, `share()` is now under `delay(7000)` and `tap()` - not working though. The `longInt$` doesn't completes --> my chrome console: long, long, long, long, fetch emit data, long, long, complete. I really appreciate your help and time you're putting into it.

Comment: hm I'm afraid I cannot find a mistake in your code. I would suggest replacing parts of the code with simpler alternatives (e.g. replace the combineLatest stuff with a simple of())  and check if it works, to narrow done the part that causes the problem. sorry I can't help more

Comment: Thanks for help @ggradnig - I accepted your answer, cause it's a correct one, even though I still have some issues in my app.